# Where is the original data set for the "German tank problem"?

Tags: data-request, historical

I am looking for the **original** data set for: the "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem" , but can't seem to find it.

Any suggestions on where it might be available from?

Comment: Hi Tal, as fascinating as an answer might be, requests for specific data sets are explicitly [off topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. (From the middle of that page: "*Questions about obtaining particular datasets are off-topic (they are too specialized).*")

Comment: Hi Glen, bummer. Since this is such a basic dataset, I thought it would fit (I didn't notice that off topic thread). I will delete the question, but how may I get an answer for it?

Comment: The dataset can be as small as a single number "4". Go and play with it.

Answer (score 3):

In the original Ruggles and Brodie (1947) paper ([PDF](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~ipollak/ece302/FALL09/notes/An_Empirical_Approach_to_Economic_Intelligence_in_World_War_II_Ruggles_Brodie_1947.pdf)) you can find some data and visualizations. It's not the raw data, but you can simulate raw data based on the percentages.

See, for example, this table:

[image]